# <Provider> is not available for module (external) hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have created the module *react-redux-area* but `hooks` in the module file dont work.

At run time I get this error:
`could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>`

I cannot see any real differents to other similar external hooks, so Im stock in my tries to fix the issue.
Any help and suggestion is really appreciated.

```
export const useMyArea = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();             // <- No problem getting context here
  useDispatchActions(myAreaActions);          // <- This line DONT work!
  useCreateActionDispatchers(myAreaActions);  // <- This line work! (Another external hook)
  // Debugging why provider dont works for useDispatchActions!
  console.log(useDispatchActions.toString());
  console.log(useCreateActionDispatchers.toString());
  //const dispatchActions = useDispatchActions(myAreaActions);
  //useDispatchActions(myAreaActions);

  // This is the function that the useDispatchActions uses internally
  // Which work fine then the dispatch is add as argument
  const dispatchActions = CreateDispatchActions(dispatch, myAreaActions);


  const areaState = useSelector((state: IStoreState) => state.myArea);
  return {
    ...areaState,
    ...dispatchActions
  };
};
```

### Module code:

The module is on gtihub:
https://github.com/alfnielsen/react-redux-area/blob/master/ReactReduxArea.ts

```
const useDispatchActions = <T extends MapMethodWithActionName<T>>(
   actionCreatorListObject: T
) => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch()
   const memoDispatchActionsObject = useMemo(
      () => CreateDispatchActions(dispatch, actionCreatorListObject),
      [dispatch, actionCreatorListObject]
   )
   return memoDispatchActionsObject
}
```

#### Sandbox example:

I have other modules that can use hook and in the example on codesandbox, and I uses this inside an app hook, that dont have the problem.

(line 44 in MyArea.ts dont work, while the same kind of external module hook works for line 45)

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-area-base-ex-s5bg1?file=/src/MyArea.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why it does not work

You bundled your library including `react-redux` (it is listed in `dependencies` section of `package.json`) so when this library is used in some app that also contains `react-redux` as a dependency it ends up with two different copies of `react-redux` (it actually depends on bundler config).
In other words, the `useDispatch` in `react-redux-action-dispatchers-hook` is not the one that is used in the app so it does not "see" App's provider.

Take a look at the stack trace in your example:

```
useReduxContext
https://s5bg1.csb.app/node_modules/react-redux/7.2.0/es/hooks/useReduxContext.js:11:11

useStore
https://s5bg1.csb.app/node_modules/react-redux/7.2.0/es/hooks/useStore.js:17:28

useDispatch
https://s5bg1.csb.app/node_modules/react-redux/7.2.0/es/hooks/useDispatch.js:14:17

useDispatchActions
https://s5bg1.csb.app/node_modules/react-redux-area/out/ReactReduxArea.js:35:36
```

`useDispatchActions` uses `useDispatch` from `react-redux` version `7.2.0` while the one, listed in the app (see packaje.json) is `7.1.1`

### How to fix it

Do not bundle `react-redux` in your library, it should be a [peer dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the same version in the package and in the project. So npm solve the dependencies, without installing node_modules inside the package.
So if you have `"react-intl": "^5.10.9"` in your project package.json fix the package package.json with the same version.